# Strange behaviour of Date.getMonth() - Month difference

Tags: javascript, date

In a project I need to convert in javascript a timestamp into a human readable string, however the number of month was incorrect so I performed the following test in a javascript console :

[image: Image of my test]

How to explain why there is a one month difference ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Months are from 0 to 11. Check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: getMonth() function is zero indexed based. You need to do date.getMonth() + 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript dates start at 0 for months

example:

- 0: Jan
- 1: Feb
- 2: Mar
- etc

Answer (score 3):

In javascript months start from 0. So January is 0, and december is 11

Answer (score 3):

[docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)

> Return value An integer number, between 0 and 11, representing the
>   month in the given date according to local time. 0 corresponds to
>   January, 1 to February, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript's `date.getMonth` starts the month count from 0. So you need to add +1.

```js
var date = new Date();
console.log(date.getMonth() + 1);
```